# Remove items from string array

Tags: c#, lambda

I have two string arrays

```
string[] a = ...
string[] b = ...
```

I want to remove any items from a that also exist in b or return a new array with only those items that exist only in a.

So, for example, if

```
a={"a", "b", "c"};
```

and,

```
b={"b"}
```

then the result should be

```
{"a", "c"}
```

Is there a neat lambda expression or Linq or something I can use to do this?

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe `Except` will do what you want.  Remember, `Except`, like most LINQ Extension methods, will not modify the existing collection.  It will return a new collection.

`c = a.Except(b)`

Comment: See also the msdn page for Except: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx

Comment: Correct, though the performance of that is O(NxM) ie. quadratic. If `a` is very large and also `b` contains many items, consider using a HashSet: `var hashA = new HashSet<string>(a); hashA.ExceptWith(b); return a.ToArray();` The performance of that is linear. If `a` is small, there is no necessity for optimization.

Comment: Why do I get cannot convert source type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> to target type string[]'?

Comment: `Except` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`.  If you want an array, you will need to call `ToArray()` on that result.